# Adding colorbar for listplot3d function

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to add a colorbar to this code when using colorfunction temperature?  Is there alternative to include colorbar and plot results similar to colorfunction method?

```
SeedRandom[1]
{part1, part3} = RandomInteger[10, {2, 10, 10}];
part2 = RandomInteger[10, {20, 30}];
i = 1;
{lp1, lp2, lp3} = ListPlot3D[#, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 10}},
 InterpolationOrder -> 3, ColorFunction -> "Temperature", 
 ImageSize -> 300, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2/3}] & /@ {part1, part2, part3};
Row[{lp1, lp2, lp3}]
```

Comment: `Legended[Row[{lp1, lp2, lp3}], BarLegend["Temperature" ]]`?

Comment: It is a good solution, however, it has a minor glitch.  When I use Placed[BarLegend[......]...] to eliminate excess white spacing between plot and legend, the size of image shrinks.

Comment: Aschoolar, maybe you can try `Style[Legended[Row[{lp1, lp2, lp3}], Placed[BarLegend["Temperature" ], ...]],  ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]`?